# Display a count on html template in Go

Tags: templates, go

Using html/templates in Go can you do the following:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="todolist">
    {{$i:=1}}
    {{range .}}         
    <tr>
        <td><a href="id/{{.Id}}">{{$i}}</a></td>
        <td>{{.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{.Description}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{$i++}}

    {{end}}
</table>
```

every time I add the $i variable the app crashes.

Comment: `"text/template"` (thus also `"html/template"`) does not implement any calculations. You need to implement your own Go function which you call from the template. In most cases the index returned by `range` action is sufficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my [html template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="todolist">
        {{range $index, $results := .}}         
        <tr>
            <td>{{add $index 1}}</td>
            <td>{{.Title}}</td>
            <td>{{.Description}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{end}}
    </table>
```

In the go code I wrote a function which I passed to the FuncMap:

```
func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

In my handler:

```
type ToDo struct {
    Id          int
    Title       string
    Description string
}

func IndexHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    results := []ToDo{ToDo{5323, "foo", "bar"}, ToDo{632, "foo", "bar"}}
    funcs := template.FuncMap{"add": add} 
  temp := template.Must(template.New("index.html").Funcs(funcs).ParseFiles(templateDir + "/index.html"))
    temp.Execute(writer, results)
}
```

Comment: 7 years later, and this answer is still useful for me. thanks man

Answer (score 9):

Check out the `Variables` section of `text/template`

http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

```
range $index, $element := pipeline
```

Comment: I'm using html/template not text/template

Comment: `html/template` simply escapes values before passing them on to `text/template`. If you look at the docs for `html/template`, you'll notice that they simply refer you to the docs for `text/template`.